# can we grant time based permissions in hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to grant time based permissions in hyperledger? Say there is party A and party B, Party A wants to sell commodity x on discounted price to just party B but they want party B to avail that offer or agree to that offer in some predefined time . Similarly lets say if there is a patient and he wants to make his health record available to some doctor or research organization for few hours or x amount of time, how that can be achieved in hyperledgere?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to create some kind of flags and then write the permissions based on the flag. eg:

```
Patient {
    /*Stuffs*/
    authorizedDoctors[]
    /*Stuffs*/
}
```

But you have to control how doctors are added to the authorizedDoctors array.

Comment: and you would then create an ACL rule that allowed `authorizedDoctors` READ access.